# Android access paused activity with broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Android MainActivity in an app (lets call it app1) that I want to access from another android app (lets call app2).

I have a broadcast receiver registered with app1 that has an onReceive method. My app2 broadcasts an intent to that receiver when I press a button in app2.

I want the receiver in app1 to then be able to access the methods and variables of the paused MainActivity in app1. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Only if `MainActivity` is what registers the receiver, via `registerReceiver()`. And that will only work while that activity is running.

Comment: Ok I've done that. The receiver is not registered in the manifest, just the MainActivity. I still can't get it to work. Does this looklike the correct thing I should be sending from app2?

Comment: final Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setAction("this-is-the-way");
        intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        intent.setComponent(
                new ComponentName("com.tablet","com.tablet.activities.MainActivity.testReceiver"));
        sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: Get rid of the `setComponent()` call and the `addFlags()` call. And your `IntentFilter` in app1 will need to use that same action string.

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you!